# Calculating a Specific Limit Using Factorization Formula

Tags: calculus, limits

Problem:

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1}{(\sqrt[4]{x})^3+(\sqrt[4]{x})^2 1+(\sqrt[4]{x})   1^2 +1^3}=\frac{1}{4}$$
Can anyone break down exactly how this problem simplifies down to 1/4, and what laws are involved? I don't know where to begin here.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**plug in 1 in the expression**

There's no simplifying involved, but the tricky thing is all those radicals, but with the knowledge that 1 to any power, or under any radical, is 1 -> it's just plug and play.

Think about it, what times what times what ... is equal to 1? Which is why you don't have to care about all those radicals when x = 1.

Answer (score 0):

Replace each $x$ with $1$, and you'll get $\frac1{1+1+1+1}=\frac14$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1}{(\sqrt[4]{x})^3+(\sqrt[4]{x})^2 1+(\sqrt[4]{x})   1^2 +1^3}\\ 
=\frac{1}{\lim_{x\to 1}((\sqrt[4]{x})^3+(\sqrt[4]{x})^2 1+(\sqrt[4]{x})   1^2 +1^3)}\\ 
=\frac{1}{\lim\limits_{x\to 1}(\sqrt[4]{x})^3+\lim\limits_{x\to 1}((\sqrt[4]{x})^2 1)+\lim\limits_{x\to 1}((\sqrt[4]{x})   1^2) +1^3}\\
=\frac{1}{\lim\limits_{x\to 1}(\sqrt[4]{x})^3+\lim\limits_{x\to 1}(\sqrt[4]{x})^2 1+\lim\limits_{x\to 1}(\sqrt[4]{x})   1^2 +1^3}\\
=\frac{1}{(\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\sqrt[4]{x})^3+(\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\sqrt[4]{x})^2 1+(\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\sqrt[4]{x})   1^2 +1^3}\\
=\frac{1}{(\sqrt[4]{\lim\limits_{x\to 1}x})^3+(\sqrt[4]{\lim\limits_{x\to 1}x})^2 1+(\sqrt[4]{\lim\limits_{x\to 1}x})   1^2 +1^3}\\
=\frac{1}{(\sqrt[4]{1})^3+(\sqrt[4]{1})^2 1+(\sqrt[4]{1})   1^2 +1^3}\\
=\frac{1}{1+1+1+1}\\
=\frac{1}{4}$$

we use the following [laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_limits):
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1}\frac{1}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{\lim\limits_{x\to 1}f(x)},$$
if $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}f(x)\neq 0$.
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1}(f(x)+g(x))=\lim\limits_{x \to 1}f(x)+\lim\limits_{x \to 1}g(x)$$
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1}(cf(x))=c\lim\limits_{x \to 1}f(x)$$
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1}f(x)=f(\lim\limits_{x \to 1}x),$$ if $f$ is continous.